# Multiple page template locations with a FluidTYPO3 provider extension

Tags: typo3, flux, fluid, typo3-9.x

how can I specify multiple page template locations with a provider extension?

- TYPO3 9.5.x LTS
- flux 9.2.0
- fluidpages 5.2.0

I have a provider extension "my_provider" and another "my_provider_extended".
I register my provider extension in "my_provider", where I save the page templates.

```
\FluidTYPO3\Flux\Core::registerProviderExtensionKey('Vendor.MyProvider', 'Page');
\FluidTYPO3\Flux\Core::registerProviderExtensionKey('Vendor.MyProvider', 'Content');
```

Now I want to extend my page templates but not in the "my_provider" extension but in "my_provider_extended".
The TypoScript configuration looks like this:

```
plugin.tx_myprovider.view {
    templateRootPath {
        0 = EXT:my_provider/Resources/Private/Templates/
    1 = EXT:my_provider_extended/Resources/Private/Templates/
    }
    partialRootPath {
        0 = EXT:my_provider/Resources/Private/Partials/
    1 = EXT:my_provider_extended/Resources/Private/Partials/
    }
    layoutRootPath {
    0 = EXT:my_provider/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    1 = EXT:my_provider_extended/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    }
}
```

If I override an existing page template from "my_provider" in the "my_provider_extended" everything is fine.

But if I add a new page template in "my_provider_extended", it will not be recognized.

The background is that I use "my_provider" extension in several projects and update it regularly.

It is the basis in all my projects, which is why the extension has to be the same everywhere. Imagine it like EXT:news.
The "my_provider_extended" extension is intended for project specific changes and overwrites, if necessary, page templates.

Now I need a special page template that I do not need anywhere else.

Is it possible to save more pages templates in other locations and use it with a Provider Extension? What needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you select your page templates you need to enhance this list.

A commonly used way is the selection of backend_layouts, which can be defined by TSconfig. which an extension can provide.
Then there is a field `layout` for each `pages` record.

and somewhere this values must be translated to the fluid-templates you are using. This is done probably in the main typoscript near `page.10.templateName`. There might be a `CASE` or similar condition.

Comment: Thanks for your very fast feedback.

No I do not use the standard `backend_layouts` but` EXT: fluidpages` extension of FluidTYPO3 for page templates. I know that `backend_layouts` uses TypoScript for the selection of page templates. This extension inserts a userfunc in `page` object and looks like this in TypoScript Object Browser:

```
  [page] = PAGE
   [5] = USER
    [userFunc] = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    [extensionName] = Fluidpages
    [vendorName] = FluidTYPO3
    [pluginName] = Page
```

Comment: as you may have seen: no formatting in comments. so add this info to your question because it is important. as I don't use fluidpages I can't help you except to say: look into the manual, and if it is not explained there: inspect the code itself (or wait until someone familiar with fluidpages might answer your question.)

Comment: Thanks for the note regarding code formatting. The manual is read and I have also read the source code and now know why that does not work.

Fluidpages extension does not respect TypoScript. It reads the standard template location of an extension so `Resources / Private / Template`.

The question is, how do I get EXT: fluidpages to respect my TypoScript.